# How to load markers instantly android

Tags: google-maps-markers, cluster-computing

I using googleMap and what i'm tring to do is to refresh markers from firebase database, and that mean i delete all the previous markers and add the new ones by using this methode

```
@Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                try{
                    MyItem myItem = new MyItem(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                    if (!items.contains(myItem)) {
                        items.add(myItem);
                    }
                    Log.d("onKey","called");
                }catch (ClassCastException e){
                    Log.d("classCastException","");
                }

            }
```

parseJsonToList methode :

```
private void parseJsonToList() {


    itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
    try {


        items.removeAll(itemss);
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        Log.d("itemsDoesn't exist"," : ");
    }


    mClusterManager.clearItems();
    mClusterManager.cluster();
    mClusterManager.addItems(items);
    Log.d("items"," : " + items);


}
```

So, my problem is that everytime I'm tring to clean and load data what happened is that all markers desapears for about 3 second to been reloaded again. How can i delete and reload data without markers dispear.

this is myItem class :

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyItem item = (MyItem) o;
        return Objects.equals(mPosition, item.mPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(mPosition);
    }
}
```